# How to put a shadow above containers inside ListView.builder Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, layout

I have a ListView.builder where I want to show containers with shadows. And I want a shadow of one container to cover another container. [Example of how it should looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEcf9.png).
It easily to do with Stack widget, but I have no idea how to do it inside ListView.builder.

**Solution that works fine for me**

Instead of using `ListView` I've decided to use `CustomScrollView` that takes `slivers` as parameters. Inside `slivers` I'm maping through a list of items and return my container wrapped with `SliverToBoxAdapter`. I don't know exactly how it works, but it works fine for me.

```
CustomScrollView(
  slivers: [
    ...names.map(
      (e) => SliverToBoxAdapter(
        child: Center(
          child: CustomContainer(
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text('Container #${e['name']}'),
                  Text('Age is ${e['age']} y.o.')
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: You simply can't make items overlap inside the ListView, that is the purpose of the `Stack` as you mentioned. May I ask the use case behind it ?

Comment: I just have a design where I have a list of items that should be shown in this way. @Wapazz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// if scroll view overflow on other widget then use ClipRRect With Expanded.

```
ClipRRect(
child: Expanded(
child: CustomScrollView(
clipBehavior: Clip.none, //add this line inside CustomScrollView
  slivers: [
    ...names.map(
      (e) => SliverToBoxAdapter(
        child: Center(
          child: CustomContainer(
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text('Container #${e['name']}'),
                  Text('Age is ${e['age']} y.o.')
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),),),
```

I face the same problem and i use this tricks and it's solved.

Comment: Thanks @Amir, that's what I need. Btw do you have any thoughts, how can I do something similar but in this time I need use shadow inside a grid view?

Answer (score 0):

You can use index of listview and give different elevation of card according to index.

```
 ListView.builder(
          itemCount:10,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
            return Card(
              elevation: (i%2 == 1)?10 :0,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text("Container $i"),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          }),
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it's not what I actually need. What l need is a shadow from one container to cover another container.